# Filtering rows from DB2 table with multiple combination of search values

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, db2-400

Say I have a DB2 table consisting of 5 columns. How should I filter rows based on any combination of a known value from each of this columns?

If I have a search value for each of the 5 columns, and I want to return rows that matches all of them, I can can simply filter it by

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE A = value1 and B = value2 and C = value3 and D = value 4 and E = value 5
```

But what if I only have search values from say columns A and B, or A and C, or A B and C, etc.
How can I make a single WHERE clause that can filter returned rows based on the available search values I have?

How can I implement the idea of the more search criteria you enter the lesser rows you'll return in one WHERE clause?

Comment: Dynamic SQL can help for this type of work. You create the query at run time dynamically by adding predicates as needed, then prepare, binding value as needed, execute, or execute immediate.  This is a FAQ.

Comment: I don't know how to implement a dynamic sql yet. What's the equivalent of this in static sql? The only idea I have is that I need to create at least 16 where clauses (for a 4 column table) for this to work.

Comment: So I did a little searching about Dynamic SQL.... will the FIXED-LIST SELECT work? Say if I only have 3/5 predicates, and this is my where clause: WHERE   A   = ?  and B = ? and C = ? and D = ? and E = ? , will this work even the two other predicates doesn't have a value?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  You've tagged both mainframe and db2-400, which are different.

Comment: mainframe and idk. does knowing help with anything?

Comment: @RogerStrycova "idk" - does it mean, that you code some JDBC application having to use such a logic?

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the specific database parser, but if you have five columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and five potentially null parameters `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` the query could take the form:

```
select *
from t
where (a = :p0 or :p0 is null)
  and (b = :p1 or :p1 is null)
  and (c = :p2 or :p2 is null)
  and (d = :p3 or :p3 is null)
  and (e = :p4 or :p4 is null)
```

Using JDBC the parameterized query could look like:

```
select *
from t
where (a = ? or ? is null)
  and (b = ? or ? is null)
  and (c = ? or ? is null)
  and (d = ? or ? is null)
  and (e = ? or ? is null)
```

Keep in mind that a query like this one offers few opportunities for optimization. Most likely the engine will need to scan the whole heap each time.